# ValueError: unsupported format character \'"\' (0x22) when formatting with dict

Tags: python

I'm currently working through the O'Reilly book, Programming Python. Below is code that reads a shelve and creates a web interface allowing you to access those values from the shelf. You can fetch and update the values

```
'''
Implement a web-based interface for viewing and updating class instances
stored in a shelve; the shelve lives on server (same machine if localhost)
'''

import cgi, sys, os
import shelve, html
shelvename = 'class-shelve'
fieldnames = ('name', 'age', 'job', 'pay')

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print('Content-type: text/html')
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())

# main html template
replyhtml = """
<html>
<title>People Input Form</title>
<body>
<form method=POST action=peoplecgi.py>
    <table>
    <tr><th>key<td><input type=text name=key value="%(key)">
    $ROWS$
    </table>
    <p>
    <input type=submit value="Fetch", name=action>
    <input type=submit value="Update", name=action>
</form>
</body></html>
"""
# insert html for data rows at $ROWS$
rowhtml = '<tr><th>%s<td><input type=text name=%s value="%%(%s)s">\n'
rowshtml = ""
for fieldname in fieldnames:
    rowshtml += (rowhtml % ((fieldname,)*3))
replyhtml = replyhtml.replace('$ROWS$', rowshtml)


def htmlize(adict):
    new = adict.copy()
    for field in fieldnames:
        value = new[field]
        new[field] = html.escape(repr(value))
    return new

def fetchRecord(db, form):
    try:
        key = form['key'].value
        record = db[key]
        fields = record.__dict__
        fields['key'] = key
    except:
        fields = dict.fromkeys(fieldnames, '?')
        fields['key'] = 'Missing or invalid key!'
    return fields

def updateRecord(db, form):
    if not 'key' in form:
        fields = dict.fromkeys(fieldnames, '?')
        fields['key'] = 'Missing key input!'
    else:
        key = form['key'].value
        if key in db:
            record = db[key]
        else:
            from person_start import Person
            record = Person(name='?', age='?')
        for field in fieldnames:
            setattr(record, field, eval(form[field].value))
        db[key] = record
        fields = record.__dict__
        fields['key'] = key
    return fields

db = shelve.open(shelvename)
action = form['action'].value if 'action' in form else None
if action == 'Fetch':
    fields = fetchRecord(db, form)
elif action == 'Update':
    fields = updateRecord(db, form)
else:
    fields = dict.fromkeys(fieldnames, '?')
    fields['key'] = 'Missing or invalid action!'
db.close()
print(replyhtml % htmlize(fields))
```

However, for some reason, printing is continually failing. I've tried many times to remove the "" the error is stating, but to no avail.

Does anyone see why this is failing to print the form?

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After checking the complete code , I believe the issue is in the `replyhtml` , in line -

```
    <tr><th>key<td><input type=text name=key value="%(key)">
```

The issue is in the format - `"%(key)"` . You need to specify the type of the element like `s` or `d` etc , I believe you may need `s` (for string). Example -

```
    <tr><th>key<td><input type=text name=key value="%(key)s">
```

Comment: Dude, you're AWESOME. Changing the line fixed the issue per your request